# Why don't we consider non-units as quadratic residues?

Tags: finite-groups

Is there any specific reason in not including non-units of $\mathbb{Z}_n$ as quadratic residues? As an examples, we say that in $\mathbb{Z}_8$, the set of quadratic residues is just {1} and not {1,4}.

Comment: If we were more inclusive, too many theorems, proofs would have to say "quadratic residue relatively prime to $n$" instead of "quadratic residue." Also, for many years the focus was almost entirely on prime $n$.

Answer (score 0):

It is a nice idea to associate with unit quadratic residues the number $1$ and with unit quadratic non-residues the number $-1$ (this is the logic behind the Legendre and Jacobi symbols).

The reason this is a nice idea is that you have the following properties of unit residues and non-residues:

> residue $\cdot$ residue $=$ residue
>
> residue $\cdot$ non-residue $=$ non-residue
>
> non-residue $\cdot$ non-residue $=$ residue

If you replace "residue" by $1$ and "non-residue" by $-1$ above, you get truthful statements about integers.

When you include non-unit residues, the above formulas are no longer correct. For example ([taken from Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadratic_residue#Composite_modulus_not_a_prime_power)), if you're working modulo $15$, then $3\cdot 5 = 9 \cdot 5 = 9 \cdot 10 = 0$. But $3, 5$ are non-residues and $9, 10$ are residues.

Comment: But this sort of thing happens only with $0$ and not other numbers, isn't it?

Comment: Try looking at modulo $30$ instead of modulo $15$... Then $9 \cdot 5 = 15$ is an example of a residue times a non-residue giving a residue.

Comment: Okay, that clarifies it. Thank you.